# Using Events/Commands with XamlReader

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, xamlreader

I am dynamically building my datatemplate using XamlReader.Parse(string). The problem I have is that I can't put any events on any of the controls I create using the XamlReader. After doing some research online I've learned that this is a known limitation of XamlReader.

I don't know a lot about commands in WPF but could I somehow use them to gain the same result? If so how? If not is there any way I can handle an event in my code behind from a control created using Xaml Reader?

Below is an example of the datatemplate I create. I have the MenuItem_Click event handler defined in the the codebehind of the Window that will host this datatemplate.

I get the following error when trying to run it: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled: Failed to create a 'Click' from the text 'MenuItem_Click'.

```
DataTemplate result = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(@"<DataTemplate 
                        xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                        xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
                            <Grid Width=""Auto"" Height=""Auto"">

                            <TextBlock Text=""Hello"">
                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                         <MenuItem 
                                          Header=""World""
                                          Click=""MenuItem_Click""></MenuItem>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>

                            </Grid>
                      </DataTemplate>");

        result = XamlReader.Parse(sb.ToString()) as DataTemplate;
```

Answer (score 5):

Hoping a late answer might help others:

I found that I needed to **bind the events after the parsing**, and had to remove the click event from the Xaml string.

In my scenario I applied the resulting DataTemplate to an ItemTemplate, wired up the ItemSource, and then added the handler. This does mean **the click event would be the same for all the items**, but in my case the header was the information needed and the method was the same.

```
//Set the datatemplate to the result of the xaml parsing.
myListView.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)result;

//Add the itemtemplate first, otherwise there will be a visual child error
myListView.ItemsSource = this.ItemsSource; 

//Attach click event.
myListView.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MenuItem_Click));
```

And then the click event needs to get back to the **original source**, the sender will be the ListView in my case that was using the DataTemplate.

```
internal void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    MenuItem mi = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
    //At this point you can access the menuitem's header or other information as needed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/03/xaml-events-in-compiled-and-uncompiled-scenarios.aspx).  Most of the solutions there will apply with `Parse` as well.  I'm not really a C# dev, so the only one I can really explain is the last one, which is something of an if-all-else-fails option:

First, you add ID's to your XAML instead of Click, etc attributes.  Then you can use [FindLogicalNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.findlogicalnode.aspx) to get at nodes, and then wire up the events yourself.

For example, say you give your MenuItem `ID="WorldMenuItem"`.  Then in your code after calling parse, you can do this:

```
MenuItem worldMenuItem = (MenuItem)LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(result, "WorldMenuItem");
worldMenuItem.Click += MenuItem_Click; // whatever your handler is
```

Comment: I can't seem to get that snippet to compile. FindLogicalNode takes a DependencyObject as it's first param and I can't figure out how to cast a DataTemplate to a DependencyObject. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I figured out how to get a DependencyObject out of a DataTemplate...I use DataTemplate.LoadContent(). Now the problem is that no matter what the MenuItem is never found. I know Context Menu's are not included in the same VisualTree as the rest of the controls, is this true for the LogicalTree as well?